# Subview on UINavigationController when pushing viewController animated doesn't look right

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

In my UIViewController viewDidLoad I have:

```
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
...
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 2, 40, 40);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:myButton];
```

Button shows just fine. No I push another viewcontroller on the stack:

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Of course the Button is still showing so I try hiding it in the viewWillDisappear and showing it in the viewWillAppear but the transitions just doesn't look right. Even swapping the order of the super calls with the hidden calls doesn't look right.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    myButton.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    myButton.hidden = NO;
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

What can I do to get this transition to look right? Thank you.

Comment: And you cannot use [UINavigationItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationItem) for placing the button?

Comment: Did you fixed this issue? same issue am facing with UIView placed on viewcontroller and animated using UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the button as subview use something like the following

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:YourCustomView];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```